# My HTML toc is not showing up in Calbre MOBI output

Tags: calibre, mobi, table-of-contents

My docx has an HTML linked TOC. I select Do Not Include table of contents and the output MOBI has the Go To Table of Contents greyed out. If I leave the Do Not include Table of Contents blank then the Go To works but links to an ugly read version of my lovely html table. Yes my html table is viewable when paging. It seems Calibre does not see my TOC bookmark in my source document. I am at a loss. 
Thank you for any help. 
Pat

Comment: Your question is not very clear; if you could improve its readability and ask more precisely what you are trying to solve, you will surely get more feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion but you could try:

1. Outputting your DOCX format to html from within MS-Word,
2. Making sure that it all works including the ToC, when it is in HTML format, *preferably using more than one browser,* and then
3. Converting the HTML format to MOBI from within Calibre -

This will save Calibre from having to deal with 2 formats at once, (DOCX & HTML), which might be the source of the problem.